# Which functions should I use to url safe search redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search input, and a redirection function in jQuery, which redirects users when they hit enter to search.

```
<input type=text class=searcher>
```

```js
$(".searcher" ).keypress(function (e) {    
    var searcher = $('.searcher').val();    
    if (searcher.length>2 && e.which == 13) {    
       document.location = 'http://www.example.com/?q=' + searcher;
    }    
});
```

However, I need to know the functions I should add to make it url safe search redirect ? (Means that changing query to URL safe if it contains `'`, `"`, `\`, `&`, `+` which breaks the script)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/

Comment: No jQuery required: `encodeURIComponent()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need JavaScript.

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/" method="get">
    <input type="search" name="q" minlength="3" />
</form>
```

The browser will take care of *everything* here. Even submitting the form: when a form contains only one input element, then the default action of hitting Enter in it is to submit the form.